# str_word_count to return links as a single word

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to use `str_word_count` to return links as a single word. I've read it has a parameter "charlist" to add characters that are considered part of a word but it seems I'm not using it properly because it still splits links I wrote `str_word_count($html, 1,'.');` for example and it seems it still splits by the point. How does it have to be called for it to return links as a single word?

Comment: may be you wanna implode array from it >?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was just setting something wrong, now for me
str_word_count($html, 1,'/.0..9_') is working